# Express.js module returning undefined value

Tags: node.js, express, request

*Middleware.js*

```
exports.initLocals = function (req, res, next) {
res.locals.navLinks = [
    { label: 'Home', key: 'home', href: '/' },
    { label: 'Blog', key: 'blog', href: '/blog' },
    { label: 'Contact', key: 'contact', href: '/contact' },
    { label: 'Gallery', key: 'gallery', href: '/gallery' },
    { label : 'Research', key : 'research' , href : '/research'},
    { label : 'Publications', key : 'publications', href : '/publications'},
    { label : 'Teaching Initiatives', key : 'teaching', href : '/teaching-initiatives'}
];
res.locals.user = req.user;
userInfo = req.user;
next();
};
```

*app.js*

```
var middleware = require('./routes/middleware');
console.log(middleware.initLocals.userInfo);
```

app.js console is outputting undefined because I am accessing the variable before the request is made. Is there any other way to get the userInfo by pre-requesting. I feel that there must be way!

Answer (score 1):

Try to print middleware.initLocals only,
or maybe the problem rely on the path which you required from it .
hope that help you :)

Comment: middleware.initLocals is a function so it prints function.So, it wouldn't work! And path is perfect

Comment: It did give function @Mahmoud

Comment: see this link , it can help u
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: The problem with mine is I have req object. It is working fine when I console it in initLocals. But when I access it from outside it is not working

Comment: ok man try this ,
var { initLocals }  = require('./routes/middleware');
that is last one, hope it works